# how to display image from byteArray coming from webservice in android?

Tags: android, arrays, imageview

friends,

i am getting following webservice response from dotnet service.

```
<Bank>
               <bankID>1</bankID>
               <bankName>AIK Banka</bankName>
               <imageByte>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</imageByte>
            </Bank>
            <Bank>
               <bankID>2</bankID>
               <bankName>Credy Banka</bankName>
               <imageByte>R0lGODlhlgBQAPcAAJGis8zT2e3t7by7u8vLy2uHpBU3WLW0s9vc3Y2kusLDw2J2itPT0/z8/K28zJOUleru8jJag5WepZSgq0dskdPb431+f3mTroSFh7K7xFtyiCVNda6zuSlTfFNshYWdtKq1wZqquvPz8+Hm69zi6RtDatHV2szR1tze4ERjgeDg4UtrjGyDm7jG09XZ3IqdsZWpvgUsVPj4+Aw0XGN6kfr6+ktjenuWsXGKo1x8nBQ8ZMnO1GRsde7x9YWLkXWRrPT2+N7g4+bm5pGmuoeSnH2Ys6Wyvoqaq/n28sPIzougtUxwlLO+yZuptkNdeLLB0E1ZZbrCyvH09uTp7l14k1Nzk/T09JyuwHqCijZRa6WsspimtFlibL7GzmlyfCtMba25xOjo6HKIn6aprPb4+S9RcwEkSVZldYCVqqCtuujm44WZrerq6qSzw2R+mamsr7fAyAAiRfb29nqLnEtphjxbe8PP2vLy80RqjgAXPPr39cHK0zVNZaOko3KGmkpmgnN8hX2RpOvo5YOSosTK0LvI1T1ZdMDGzOzr6WWBnnGNqc3W3/Px77i9wnJ2e2p9ke/v8P37+fb08+Ph3yBCY//9+sfM0vXz8MfR2/r7/Kuwtk5ebFh2lDtfhFBcZ3eOpL3BxbjCzf/+/AAdQgstTzRWd+Ll5ypCWUpXY8bN1G2BlLG2ufv8/dDOzb7L2MfGxXCDluDf3fX29r++vr3EyyJIbqiutP////z+/lF1mJ+mrefr8EJmiqqppz9SZGBnb6S2yDdYevr5+NrZ1x08XPPx8bvDzLq4t+/s6fn6+7GvrgMoTS1KZyBFaunp6f39/dHQ0MLM18rIxxExUent8O/u7ebk4bi2tf/9/PPy8ePi4ePj5I2ap6i5yVd4mSdGZP7+/v///fHx8f7//4aXp/v7+//+/+fn6MHBwJ2enk9vjsDI0P/+/f3+/o2WoPn5+fv6+fLy8jpVb9jf5tbV1HiImMHL1cTL0/P19/X19ejp6+jq68jJyevp6UJYbH9/fyH5BAAAAAAALAAAAACWAFAAAAj/AP8JHEiwoMGDCBMqXMiwocOHEB/emkixosWLGDNq3Mixo8ePIEN2FCiypMmTKFOqzEhypcuXMGOKbCmzps2bK2ni3MmzJ0adPoMKrQl0qNGjJ4siLSljHoluRZQkUAKjAokRS10qzcqRjB0AVNSVKrVhQ4ezHSIE61QFDZMp47iW3Cr3IgQAKWbEmKGjRK2zEQJHKFtCx4wZZVgEAFf3I93GE/cEi2HmcN8SZgUH7rChVmG9ZijhoHbrGWPIP/+hzthmRpwYe/n6zayZc4nPepeZ8XCOnenVFh/XHVHGDOzYfWvR3sy5Ge7jZsRkE1buNPBbwrOWy9di2XHks9Nq/y5bS4fh72aCoRAho8H1idmXkhhCzYNx2JbD1yZsXi9s74MgEIY4NVi3WnxIFVJCACM4YYZ3+Skn3mZlNWOYf8vM8Mgr0KggwDvPvIfgUSN8Ic88KrCgA37JASYYZxt8dlwd7syCDgFBCCBDiNeNaNQ4LnzRTBMIgPJIKbf1tVwEnJVn3hd/DHLNK/W4Q8824oAoomrvySBMBR7EYMgEryigBTew0LDCCkuoo84SdKSgDg2qcKPLGK+8MsgXWmhzjggFbvneLQGkIco5YGjQTCkezKELB42swsGkk2qihS1a6KLpKo3QYMAc2ghRjRzuCfoeJqXco8cJOySxBQsp0P/RyZw05OCGG1S44ccg3GgCSiNzfNPMBCpsg4g47Q3q41DYfFILCAisQwshSexgCRwggAHCtttmAAooGXBDQxnN+GEJImAQAgmypfbI5XuZ4EDJAhkg4AIIW6yxBQBr9PvCGmig4YY6f6TgRhq0mICEJcFEcckdyZp6HQkmVGKMBzr8EQgcJgRgDBNKADAEAAAo8UIacMBh7T1RuBBKGRqEUY0I77QL3LJC2ePBPpW4AEcgf5SSAicBZ0CLMcaE0oURawCwRRr3oLADCwb8gUI1AtBs84HvAidLCn/oc0IUJ5yQChwif1IADmzjEAIMRtxjwgkg0NDMFxMIEQQCM9f/rGzXwC1SRx0ZoFBoGgBwu4MJLriQyrZp4EBFCnVosIUL1SCCAwCMWOG3xMBJIYsQGKcAAOOWgAGAHwD8kEgiOXCCQwEsNAHGCS4QYgkyLzQDRzZa/z1oNGgIU0wosDhRRhXkGLGOJamcYMLc9yRxiDHbGkGICyfQoEMTyEASPOirzVNGGpGYED0YaLDgZiJVJHLBD/xyEggA2uc+ByVfGFHNOQKA2NZQgzOhXEEHgXCBCbpQvROsI3qhaAMIutGFHViQFiAAWhmccAQXIMEIXWAEu4T3nnaAwwjNKMMWTKCCQ4QgEC+YHQ4UUYACvE4ddPgDFTZWtkvAoRSEyEY8/yLmrkGRgBC3MIEbvvAFNxghAAHYwceYwAT8MUFbXUgFtaKwDheAoRli6EfWPlfE9wQgBfOoBAru8SpZUYEKawjBFrYwMiU0YQufCNk6EHAIKpTrHGwY4wAhU0Cf1MANdcBdFwghPVrAIQRrUIIkTbaGNGRgcZaYABXK4AE4IAIRgRxfGd8TBjpQghzTM4YRQgCADKyjC7A0BhxUGYhPVCFWgWAC39jgDDZAwgo14NEogcMYEayhFl/4BBO414UQXOEFa6NdItbwAgBEgRDTiwItztFLAbDLQFwbFDjKIQM5uOAIfyhDClighAyAwRKNU+ACjQCCJoTACIdwASgDKf8OOZRDmMMETgNkkI1LMGIbO8iXGxLBiRzUMBEsQAMOxLAFJpxABWEApQAgAbF/Dgo+gFvNOGUQDwEIAGu8PIcahLCNlm5DG9sQghDCwAaablQcnmvAbz5aSJ+A4xnkjAckBFDTMJxDpjINg1KXatN1WUEGwQQn+a4DjgbUQA5WEEc1UOqMrrLhq4E8aTXikQ+o6lSqU32PgcKBVXG4NR7xEAF7RJERtAbUIz3oxgduMARMPOEHN7hBEQZ7gw88oQa36MYFBsvYwCYgAYJlrBKeQIZMBLYIP4jGLVyhiCIU1hQyeIdoR9uAClyWsR9wABBukYkEXECwN2gDOMZBjcD/XsABtxhHNwBLWMKOwBWL5asdPMtYKahkWfNIxBJ48Qc2LQEPb8LDCsC2AgoAAAgwqAIF8JCC7tJhCblwwxIoULA/UIACP5hHDlYg3TkgoxDjZe4YinGLnz7jvrfYARXOW97q/kAEZEjECjix3SUkoQEjoMJyvRGASLyATXiggzq2m4JGOAAPFOAFHeagDgLjAQ9NuERKRjQOCBSAvDywAAb8kIslSAANS3CEiiUAPw4gIAM50IAjfPAAZbxgCRNYQy688A8M+MAP6D0GN3JBgz4I4RYfWMIZLHAASFzkGWwgQAGq4IgiP0AMFNiCNRQwizUswRtLCIQgBEAPNJxX/xGmYMAxPrEEDOgiER54QCwckAsP8AAD6ThAI3JQhfAyYMQh3cgV8KABKreCAK1AAy80oQQKEEEasUDGEJZABEFUIAdUUIYaTFGNRTdhCFXwwSuG0YpX4IACWmgzBUIAjhGs9x8KYANiL9IOSPygCg9gAALUwIQlqKIVwhhBAdThg1xQgQDtqEQCKMCJJWQACZAoQhXGcIIc4IDYuaADD/rAAGfooRtL8IN4bSEDlIxIComogwVmAYl/VgIGTnjDGjrBgUqwtgCdwAIySLAEN1hjHJxYwwQ8oAUl8MIHsbhFA+ARgggEIhY7UAcegnCFCHihDwLYiAwKsAR+UAQGwf/QwCs22wkP9CIRndiCHm6hhE6oohNuOMctfpACW7hgCZ8AAXM/jgLENkARwfABNzohBmu4O9EZIUEKDJGObVSEAQ+AhhhqMYcrbIEKG8iCDxgxjzr8YQtXUGc6egENNJTBByqgCBO+sABoXGICtYhTGbBAgEFShAxUKMULrhACMYwFAwwwRyBKwINZGKEWC4g4GppBBEWl4RYsKMMbXEC5YNQCEMpAwK4XUYosPIAQZajDIZ4OkgowIwvHkEVF5KANYTyCFMQwACkMwAcvHCASi/iCAYiRe9hLQgZiMAAWJjGRcYSCGDaQBjZiESYDQKEXbOgKHaaRewNMIwZZ0IL/JHZBCWYoQw+RKAUxVnELMZDCB1swQB1MQQVijMEEX+C+AbKwA3ZMBBwAEAMLMAy3QAOkQASSkBRQhxGm8A0GMAvJYBGMQQVx4AleEAMG4APHoA1JpAMG8AtYYAbfcAhBkAkssAzLRxFbEAebIA3jEAlJEAPT8A8EUA4cAQSGQAqb8Au/wAW+YAZZAAkhEAdfQA5b0ASGMAqPcAtuMApYMAweMApH4AGkMAYBQAwxwAM2MAoLsFq3QAbMYAaPMAFNoAGjIA8IoIAgkQk2kAcTgBHjsAB54AjooAF5sADn4B4BYACnkA7o4A9e4AffkAr1EAeAwIETYYe/QAATIQPc/5cOOscRciAP0+ADA4AOA9AKThAHIJCEo5AHoDgKcXAKkfAIeYAFsUALu5cFVXgCfPgAx/ANo6AJE9EFcRAHoAiKcbAMtiAMJuEjTTAKzBAAFbEH5FCAozABl8AAxGAGljARKGAA8sB8iCAIfjAKYDAHyyAB4TARxkAKZoABcTcR03AK0vARhmAA6FARVEgD3OcFPegI6SAPcZAEsJAH6RAJ5iCHZjAN6BCNvkAPkaALwigOyAgFXsAFPJAOHpAHS/iLC3gR46ANm5AHxDAHiLMAuhECm/gIASAKRDAKTqA65EAKzGA722IDcfAINrAMsFBPsGAAceALvSAHXbAtuP9HDuvAESNgBJQwDUeQLWnwCMtADFkQB/IgAeggDQgAAg35ByqpCkYACVc4CgbQBNxgkluwC5DQhnOwBdOwDBqgCQSAAFHwCHHwDWDghSHhI1bQCJtgBnnwiXlgAFygG2YwCjagAirADHmwDNNgBnFgBoS5DMsQB6RACoM5mJ8YB3zgA9BwC4YwmII5CnwwCXZ1C2AQA6NAmA/yidNgAIJpBsSgADKAD4E5moQZBxLQD7AwCtMQhovJDZGgBYeZB5TpBWHQAA4imNPQCL7YlhF5EeAgAAPgA78ABZ7wZ33gBVAABajgCNIgDrrgCdbpCc+Znc+JndmJCp7ABfJIACL/UA4SwAWo8JyowAMK0A4aYQJegJ3nCZ2/4Ag8YJ1QwAUHIAdk4APcGZ9Q8AAI0Ao8oJBckJ0PIAQoAAiosKALagH0IAwTUKCowAW9QF/CWRJWgADSMAAD8AoMoAIMcA0HcAwKoAI1IAQKcAAHIKIq2qIu2qLHgA6toALZcAusoAIDwKLHMAsogA11JQ6twKIqeg2zQAD8MAArOgv0QAblMAzH8KLHQABZAw02MgsiOgD8AAkyQA9PegDKcAyvIATJoAKzoKIDwAByMBPDqRHlgFU7InFWIAJWAEyNGKdxJVd4mqd4mg/5YIMU8QxykKd0uhHvEKd4agX5UAPbIVee/8MYDZAPeioCchAijyoHgSpXk3oL5WCoctWnpSEHdyoDmckSa/pRpsp6p5qqMdFTUmBcFdEAJFABPRAXGwEEZHALU2AzI2AVGAEBu1YRPVABu3ARPcAK4AABF5EJPWAREDAPFUAazdcDEdgDbDkRvkqsFeCqamgSzxAVFkEC3vABRQCtGvEEmFAISnCrEwEE3qAEP+AKFTEO8BYKFlFbH/ADJFARz5AAU0AGP3AR8zAEFcEKrvUBdkAR7QADLQAOH4AJFSEFOdACFrELe/UBy7qtJTEFrhWBFFEBMDAOT9ANHFEIMKAEFzsRPXADtxANAlsRdvABCWAR3SCyJECu9f/Fr2RwARdBAh9LEckADCNAqxThCjAABDeADy4LsxbxBBK7CMiKsSLhCjfwAw7bsTFbAVewEeDQAhSQtRVBBg6VA1MQryWrCDYLDBVgBwWAWxQBDgmwC8mgs98KAxWBCwlQAD9wsBSxCwrbshQxBEpgthWBtqWRCagqEm77AR/QsxNRATHbDU/AESELA3qLskWAD0owrBQBAReQAD9QCBXhAFlbCF77f0MwD9n2tYuwCHTrs8BADUI7EftaAFVrrZ37uaErssCQr1CrEeAkBSpbDjdwBxQxAt7wA+nKES3gtBdwslJQBLdgB62bW6x7C4swBNYBBIF7A7xLEYugCIqvULusBQM5ULm3kLAFoAhsSxEt4A3aCg7Ve73W0QMfgAMwoK4Q2RHgwBjWAQ6sMBENYCBkIAV+VxHtwJ7JwJ5/OhEcOxGs8L82ahHtIAUN/LXVKrsXbKP4IAX4SxEQ7ME84qceLAUK3LsYsb+nsb8hMaqqahQ91cIwDFIxPMP5S8M27BilesM2/MI6zFM53MMxzMNAfFdD3MNCXMQE9MNIfKoR0cRO/MRQHMVSvBABAQA7</imageByte>
            </Bank>
```

if i receive imageByte in String and what should i do to display it in imageview?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`Drawable.createFromStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) on ByteArrayInputStream, constructed from your strings.

Comment: i have parsed webservice response so above imagebyte inside string format where as byteArrayInputStream supports byte[] not string. if i convert string to byte[] would it disturb actual values of imagebyte?

Comment: Nothing stops you from the try.

Answer (score 0):

I have usednext code to save image from web:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

For converting String to byte array you may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa) topic.

Comment: i have parsed webservice response now that byte data is in string format. not URL.

Comment: I know, but you anyway must transfer your string into byteArray, or something like this.