# parsing uploaded csv file with JSF ManagedBean

Tags: java, maven, jsf, csv, jsf-2

I have a maven web application in which I use JSF and spring. I want to parse a csv uploaded file with fileUploadListener. The file is uploaded, but I don't know how to get data from it and store it in database:

```
 <h:outputLabel value="Choose your file : *" />
                 <p:fileUpload  mode="advanced"  fileUploadListener="#{campagneMB.handleFileUpload}" update="growl"
              sizeLimit="4000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/"/>
```

my file has this form:

```
xxxx#xxxxx#xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be related to Java more than JSF. You should read the file's content in the listener method by [FileUploadEvent#getFile()#getContents()](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile.html#getContents%28%29) which returns `byte[]`, then just ["convert"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214471/2459449) it to `String`, which makes storing data in DB easier.
This link can be useful: [How to read and parse CSV file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/).