# Java storing type information along with Byte[] array from toBytes

Tags: java, json, encoding

I'm storing JSON information in a database, and I want to convert all values to bytes before storing, BUT retain type information.

So, for the types String, Integer, and Boolean, I want to be able to say:

```
Byte[] bytes = toBytes(myStr);

// Not too sure about this part... 
// Want type information to be retrieved somehow.
String s = fromBytes(bytes);
```

What's the best way to do this in Java?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673059/converting-byte-array-to-string-java) question covers serializing a string with arbitrary contents into a byte array. My question covers how to serialize an arbitrary JSON type without loisng type information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting byte array to String (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673059/converting-byte-array-to-string-java)

Comment: Have you looked at the gson library? https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: To my understanding this is actually not a duplicate of asking how to de/serialize arbitrary strings as byte arrays. You're welcome to explain why you think otherwise, though!

Comment: It doesn't look like gson will let me deserialize an unknown type. All the calls need to be of the from `gson.fromJson("1", int.class);`. From the gson docs: "However, deserialization with fromJson(json, Collection.class) will not work since Gson has no way of knowing how to map the input to the types. Gson requires that you provide a genericised version of collection type in fromJson. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to append one character to the end of the String, as a "code" for type.

For example, you can add a `s` for `String`, `i` for `Integer`, `f` for `Float`, and so on...

When you un-parse it as a `String`, you can remove and retrieve the last character, and then change it to the correct form accordingly.

For example:

```
// encoding
Byte[] bytes = toBytes(myStr + "s");

// decoding
String s = fromBytes(bytes);
String type = s.substring(s.length()-2);
s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
switch(s) {
    case "s":
        // leave it as is - already a string
        break;
    case "i":
        // convert it to integer
        // ... and so on
}
```

Comment: @EleazarEnrique But it's an easily reversible operation, and you don't have to add another field in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add an object field in JSON to identify the type.  For example, "type": "integer" or "type": "String" and so on.

I can't see another way.

Comment: There are no "tag"s in JSON, only object fields.