# How to convert audio string back to audio bytes in java

Tags: java, string, javasound

Bytes of recorded audio was sent together with HTTP request body. When the request is received on the server side, the audio data looks like this:

```
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0002\u0000������4\u0000M\u0000@\u0000%\u0000\u0014\u0000����������\u0015\u0000M\u0000r\u0000�\u0000_\u0000C\u0000^\u0000V\u0000\u0007\u0000��\"\u0000;\u0000>\u0000\u0005\u0000����������������\f\u0000+\u0000K\u0000e\u0000.\u0000������������\u0003\u0000\b\u0000����������\"\u0000G\u0000V\u0000(\u0000 \u0000\u0004\u0000����������\u0003\u0000W\u0000�\u0000Z\u0000a\u0000{\u0000,\u0000��������\u001E\u0000��������1\u0000\u001A\u0000\u0011\u0000(\u0000/\u0000\u0016\u0000��������0\u0000/\u00002\u0000;\u0000������d�������\u001F\u00009\u00006\u0000j\u0000[\u0000'\u0000������������\u000E\u00009\u0000%\u0000����\u0015\u0000(\u00003\u0000+\u0000'\u0000������<\u0000F\u0000=\u0000h\u0000�\u0000M\u0000��������������T\u0000i\u0000]
```

How can I convert this string back to the original audio data bytes?

I tried calling getBytes() but it doesn't seem right.

----- EDIT -----

Posting the code for HTTP Request would be too long. I'll cite a short sample here.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    byte[] test = new byte[]{(byte)0xfc, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff};

    String testString = new String(test);

    System.out.println(testString);

    System.out.println(getHexString(testString.getBytes()));
}

public static String getHexString(byte[] bytes) 
{
    char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) 
    {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;

        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }

    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

The code above gives the following result

```
����
EFBFBDEFBFBDEFBFBDEFBFBD
```

When I convert bytes FC, FF, FF, FF to string, I get ����. When I convert the string back to bytes I get EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD. I want to get the original bytes FC, FF, FF, FF from ����.

Comment: That very depends on details such as encoding, file formats, and most importantly: how exactly your http request is built from. Please provide a [mcve], right now your question is on a level of "hello doctor, my cat is making strange noises. now tell me whats wrong with her".

Comment: If you can post the code that was used to _produce_ the HTTP request on the client side, perhaps someone can help.

Comment: @GhostCat Hi, I just edited my question.

Comment: @user31601 Hi, I just edited my question

Comment: *byte* is a *signed* type. 0xFF is not a valid byte!

Comment: And you probably want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673059/converting-byte-array-to-string-java

Comment: @GhostCat technically, casting the literal 0xFF to byte, will result in a byte of value -1, which is the value immediately lower then zero, so the same value as 0xFF in hexa unsigned notation. That syntax is fairly accepted and behaves as expected.

Comment: Note also that the edit does **not** contain an MCVE we can work with. Please **read** the document linked by @GhostCat. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are meant to represent text. Audio data is not text. Try as you may, it is not possible to shove some audio data in a String, then try to extract back your audio data out of the String. It is designed to not work.

As the audio data you want to work with are not text, then you have no rationale to want to involve String in the process. Forget about Strings, you now know that they are not a suitable tool for your goal, so leave them alone completely. Binary data such as audio, can be represented as **sequences of bytes**. Such as a byte[] array for instance.

Remove the variable `String testString`. Don't build it, don't declare it, remove it entirely. It's a String, and you can't use Strings for your goal, so get rid of it.

Instead, let's focus on using your variable `byte[] test` as it is. It's already a byte[] and it contains all the data. So it's all you need.

You can write it with `System.out.write(test);` but in the console that's not very useful. In a socket's OutputStream that's perfect though.

Or you can write out the hexadecimal encoded version of it with:

```
System.out.println(getHexString(test));
```

Here you obtain a fully functional result. Decoding them back to bytes will give you exactly the bytes you started with.

Comment: I agree, you captured the essential problem with strings here. But then: we really dont know anything about how those audio data is coming in on his http request. In other words: you addressed those parts of the question that can in fact be answered. Anything else is unclear...

Comment: @GhostCat Of course. Still, it's important enough to be said and insisted on: Strings are the wrong tool to work on non-text binary. If you're working with non-text binary and you're putting it in a String at some point, then you've failed and your program won't work. Since it's the inevitable consequence, then, *don't* use String for anything else but text.