# in Java, which encoding scheme is 8-bit US ASCII?

Tags: java, encoding, ascii

I want to write a string to a file which expects an `8-bit US ASCII` encoding.

Which encoding scheme should I use for the method `String.getBytes(encodingScheme)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASCII is a 7bit encoding scheme, there is no "8-bit ASCII".

However, many encodings are ASCII-compatible, and some are 8bit transparent (i.e. every binary series maps to a valid character string, and vice versa, useful if you're sending binary data over a character channel without encoding it in base64 or so). If you just want to be ASCII-compatible, `UTF-8` is the best choice; if you need 8 bit transparency, `ISO-8859-1`.

Note that the above advice is only useful if you want to transport ASCII-only strings or 8bit binary ones. In most cases, you actually want to transfer arbitrary *strings*, and there's no way around finding the proper encoding for these.

Comment: Many thanks. WHat's the difference between "8-bit compatible" and "8-bit transparent"?

Comment: @Martin08 Added an explanation to the answer. I meant (7bit) ASCII-compatible

Comment: @Ted Hopp You got 90% of the way to the reason. Imagine a channel **above** the text channel, and you're there.

Comment: @phihag - Sorry, I deleted my comment after seeing your response to Martin08. Why would you send binary data to a process that expects character data (or vice versa)? There's no reason to prefer ISO 8859-1 over any other encoding unless you know what the other end is using.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Maybe because said process was never designed to handle binary data, but it's a useful feature? Maybe because the data you're sending *contains* the charset and you don't want to parse it yourself? (think an HTML document with a `<meta charset>` tag). You're right in as there's no reason to prefer ISO-8859-1 over, say, ISO-8859-15, but in these cases you should *not* use UTF-8, as certain binary sequences are not valid UTF-8.

Comment: @Francois - I don't think that works. Although every 8-bit value is a legal character in ISO 8859-1, some of the characters (like CR) have special meaning in MIME messages. Plus, MIME is a 7-bit protocol. So the channel itself isn't transparent. I'm not even sure what it means to use ISO 8859-1 "to send binary content" without first using some binary-to-text encoding scheme. While Base64 is about 75% efficient, some other encoding schemes are much better (e.g., yEnc is ~98% efficient). Also, if one uses 8BITMIME, then there's no need for any character encoding at all to send binary data.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - Absolutely, ISO8859-1 is not equivalent to 8bit encoding in a MIME message. I'm withdrawing my comment.

Answer (score 4):

US-ASCII

The list of encodings is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as "8-bit ASCII". There are several 8-bit "extensions" to ASCII, including [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Those are probably the most common ones, but they're not the same. You really need to find out *exactly* which encoding is expected.

Both of those names are available *via* those names in Java - at least they are on my JDK installation. (You may find that Windows-1252 isn't available on a Linux installation, for example.)

Comment: There is the extended ascii, i.e. at the bottom of this page: http://www.ascii-code.com/ There are also lots of 8-bit variants of ascii: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#8-bit

Comment: @Tamas: There's no one encoding properly named "extended ASCII" - there are just several 8-bit extensions, each of which is probably called "extended ASCII" somewhere. In other words, if something identified itself as using "extended ASCII" it would be almost useless.