# how to convert Byte code to String?

Tags: java, android, byte

I am using a 3rd party application.
In that application, the input word "test" gets converted to byte code output.
the byte code value is appreaing as `[17, 17, 17, 17, 34, 34, 34, 34, 51, 51, 51, 51, 68, 68, 68, 68]`

I do not know how to convert this byte code to a readable text value (text value: "test").

I am trying this on an Android application.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Not sure if this is duplicate, but definitly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6684665/620197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[] c = new char[] {17, 17, 17, 17, 34, 34, 34, 34, 51, 51, 51, 51, 68, 68, 68, 68};
    String word = String.valueOf(c);
    System.out.println(word);
}
```