# How to convert byte array to string?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to covert the bytes into string what I am getting after reading from bluetooth device. Below is the code I am using, but it is not giving proper string. 
Output is like this

02-19 18:01:49.300: I/BluetoothReadService(17693): Message Read : ���8��1.04TTO��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Read from the InputStream                    
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    String readMessage = null;
                    byte[] getBytes = null;
                    try {
                        readMessage = BitConverter.toString(buffer);
                        getBytes = BitConverter.getBytes(readMessage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String s = new String(getBytes, "US-ASCII");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Message Read : "+readMessage +"ByteString"+s);
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
```

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array
Google is your friend.

Comment: Are you sure the bytes contain an US-ASCII-encoded text?

Comment: use this `String str = new String(bytes, Charsets.US_ASCII);`

Comment: What does BitConverter do and why are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

The readMessage String should be initialized in a different way.
If you use `readMessage = new String(buffer);`, it should work.

Comment: No, i have tried all this, but getting the same result.

Comment: Could you try `String readMessage = Arrays.toString(buffer);` ? It represents the number values of the bytes. It might just be that they're out of range of a normal String character. Maybe you can compare them that way?

Answer (score 0):

By `apache StringUtils` you can use this method [from document](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html)

```
 public static String newStringUsAscii(final byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(bytes, Charsets.US_ASCII);    
  }
```

And if still the problem persists than use below method for reading the String

```
public String readData() {

    String response = null;
    int bytesReceived=-1;
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    try{

        try{
            bytesReceived = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            Logger.debugLog(MODULE ,"# Byte Receieved #" + bytesReceived);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Logger.errorLog(MODULE ,"Error in readData() , Reason:"+e.getMessage(),e);

        }
        if(bytesReceived > 0){          
            response = new String(readBuffer,0,bytesReceived);

            Logger.debugLog(MODULE + "Total Bytes Received: " + bytesReceived);
            Logger.debugLog(MODULE, "Total Time Taken : " + timetoread);
            Logger.debugLog(MODULE, "Length of data received : " + response.length());
            Logger.infoLog(MODULE, "Data Received : ####" + response + "####");
        }else{
            ////////// HERE MEANS TCP CONNECTION STATUS WILL CLOSE_WAIT
            ////////// SO RELEASING CONNECTION.
            Logger.infoLog(MODULE, " Releasing Resource. bytesReceived is <= 0 : Total Bytes Received :"+ bytesReceived );

                releaseResources();

            }
            Logger.infoLog(MODULE, " Resource has been released.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Logger.errorLog(MODULE, "In catch : Data Received : ####" + response + "####");
        Logger.errorLog(MODULE, "Exception in readdata() : " + e);
    }finally{
        readBuffer=null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
String s = new String(getBytes, "US-ASCII");
```

you should use

```
String s = new String(buffer, "US-ASCII");
```

and remove that part with BitConverter.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to ignore the number of bytes actually read and create the new String out of the entire buffer of 1024 bytes.

Try this instead:

```
String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes, "US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Android's official [Bluetooth Chat example](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.html#l482), in `BluetoothChatFrangment.java`, you see this:

```
// construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
```

in this example `msg.arg1` is equal to `bytes` in your case. Also `readBuf` is `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you.

```
String s = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Requires Api above KitKat.