# ByteArrayInputStream() shows null

Tags: java, mysql, bufferedimage

I am trying to load an image which is in a MySQL database as blob data format  (`[B@e96bf`) but I can't load it to a JLabel as shown below. It shows the `ByteArrayInputStream` is empty.

```
byte[] bytesl = null;

ResultSet rs = DB.DB.search("select image from imageio where id = '2'");
while (rs.next()) {
    bytesl = rs.getBytes(1);               
}
BufferedImage imag = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesl));

Image img = imag;

img = img.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight(),
                            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Comment: What type is `DB`? A good start would be putting a print statement in the while loop (or debug your code) to see if it ever goes in there. Shouldn't affect your result, but if the while loop is supposed to only execute at most once (I'm assuming...), you probably shouldn't be using a while loop (an if statement comes to mind as a better idea).

Comment: have you verified the column and row have data?

Comment: you i verified with an sout... [B@e96bf this is wht i got for bytesl  do i have to decode it?

Comment: `[B@e96bf` is (most likely) not what's actually stored in your byte array (if it is, that's a problem), that's just what Java prints out when you try to sout an array. Try `Arrays.toString` or `new String(bytes)` before passing it to `println`. [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6684665). Also, you should probably show us the way you wrote data to the `image` column in your table, in case there's a problem there. If at all possible, you should always try to give us complete (but short) code we can just run instantly on our side to see the same result as what you are seeing.

Comment: File f = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
            String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(path);
            newpath = path.replace("\\", "/");
            File f2 = new File(newpath);
            Image img = ImageIO.read(f2);
            img = img.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

            fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(f2.toPath());
DB.DB.statement("insert into imageio (image) values ('" + fileContent + "')");

Answer (score 0):

I think you code doesn't go to while loop, because there's no records with such query. Most probably issue is the ' signs around 2. Usually id is a number, but in your request it looks like you compare it to string. Try to remove apostrophe signs around 2.

Comment: that's just the mysql query... problem found is  i get null value for ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesl))

Comment: no mate there is no issue in database..  there are 2 columns. id(int), image(blob)

Comment: precisely id is int, but you pass a string. Try query: select image from imageio where id = 2

Comment: this is a java program... so i pass this query as a string statement :)

Answer (score 0):

```
fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(f2.toPath());
DB.DB.statement("insert into imageio (image) values ('" + fileContent + "')");
```

You've just inserted the string `[B@96bf` *into* the database. `ImageIO` can't turn that into an image, so it returns null.

You should at least use a `PreparedStatement` and provide the data as an argument. You should really be using a Blob and an input stream here.