# ByteCode representation to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays

if I do something like this :

```
img.getImageBytes(); /*returns byte[] from image */
```

How can I do the inverse with the string that represents that byte[] ?

Comment: have you tried str.getBytes() function?

Comment: What do you mean by *string that represents that byte[]*?

Comment: @uniquephase I already tried with no success.

Comment: @Ashraf Purno I mean the sequence of characters you get from printing a byte[].

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are printing the byte array. But assuming you are using it's `toString()` method or `Arrays.toString()` method.

Then you take the string representation of the `byte[]`, strip off leading `[` and rearing `]` and split it by `,` into a `String[]`. Now create a new `byte[]` with the same size of the `String[]`. Then iterate over the `String[]` and convert each element and add to the `byte[]`. Example

```
    byte[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //Initial byte array also can be gotten from any other source
    String s = b.toString(); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    String[] sa = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(",");
    byte[] ba = new byte[sa.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
        ba[i] = Byte.valueOf(sa[i].trim());
    }

    //Now ba should contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedImage yourImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes_array_of_image));
```

Comment: Your solution receives a byte[]. I need it ro receive a String or learn a way to convert the String to byte[]. Already tried string.getBytes()

Comment: Will string.getBytes() not help you?