# Java get string from byte array

Tags: java, string, byte, arrays

I am modding a java program and in it a handler receives 2 byte arrays
When I print those arrays using a line of code like this\

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(this.part1))
```

I get an output like this

```
[43, 83, 123, 97, 104, -10, -4, 124, -113, -56, 118, -23, -25, -13, -9, -85, 58, -66, -34, 38, -55, -28, -40, 125, 22, -83, -72, -93, 73, -117, -59, 72, 105, -17, 3, -53, 121, -21, -19, 103, 101, -71, 54, 37...
```

I know these byte arrays contain a string. How might I get that string from them?
Here is the code

```
    public void readPacketData(PacketBuffer data) throws IOException
{
    this.field_149302_a = data.readByteArray();
    this.field_149301_b = data.readByteArray();
    String packet1 = (java.util.Arrays.toString(this.field_149302_a));
    String packet2 = (java.util.Arrays.toString(this.field_149301_b));

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Byte Array to String to Byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: Please provide code snippet

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert Byte array into String format correctly, we have to explicitly create a String object and assign the Byte array to it. You can try this:

```
String str = new String(this.part1, "UTF-8"); //for UTF-8 encoding
System.out.println(str);
```

Please note that the byte array contains characters in a special encoding (that you must know).

Comment: +w?çP"aâ±ÊC³„JÜ—Ó¹vÈÚ Ð­x<Z¾^xýºonOB¥Ùâ‚-ô€AœJ¤ÄEfûÑ6øŠAŠ?I˜XmZQÄe—YÖêÛ".• qìr½sa$2±n}*™¥iÛd„×7NæmfG–".˜AÎÅó

Comment: This is what it outputs for some reason

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a constructor from `byte[]`, so you could just call `new String(this.part1)`, or, if the bytes do not represent a string in the platform's default charster, use the overloaded flavor and pass the charset too.

Answer (score 0):

actually to convert bytes to String you need encoding name. You need to change UTF-8 to correct encoding name in first answer to avoid wrong output, try UTF-16 or one of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html (try to choose by your locale).