# Data conversion from byte array to String

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert Byte Array to String with Following code snippet. But for some reasons, when i convert the byte[] to string, it changes the some content in in file

**Code**

```
public String convertToString(byte[] byteArr)
  {
    public static final int BYTE_MASK = 0xFF;
    StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < byteArr.length; i++ ) {
      strBldr.append((char) (byteArr[i] & BYTE_MASK));
    }

    return strBldr.toString();
  }
```

I have added the data of two files called expected file and generated file

**Expected File:**

```
00 39 00 00 46 91 00 00 00 17 16 02 16 16 39 31
0b 00 3a 00 78 09 60 40 26 64 50 41 50 20 48 49
47 20 52 4d 20 20 04 00 80 4b 02 00 a0 ea 01 00
64 00 ec 05 00 00 00 00 00
```

**Generated File:**

```
00 39 00 00 46 3f 00 00 00 17 16 02 16 16 39 31
0b 00 3a 00 78 09 60 40 26 64 50 41 50 20 48 49
47 20 52 4d 20 20 04 00 3f 4b 02 00 a0 ea 01 00
64 00 ec 05 00 00 00 00 00
```

if you see both files, then expected file data should be "91"(First row,sixth element) and its 3f in generated file.

Any idea how would get a correct output?

Comment: tried: new String(byteArr); ?

Comment: How are you converting the bytes back to a byte[] ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Byte Array to String to Byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: Is this really text data? Otherwise you should not try to stick it into a String. And if it is, you need to make sure the encoding is correct (and I am not sure that there is one that matches your current method of conversion).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        String example = "This is an example";
        byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();
        System.out.println("Text : " + example);

        String s = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println("String : " + s);
```

output:

Text : [B@187aeca

String : This is an example

Comment: Did you try that with the data provided in the question?