# convert an int to string

Tags: java, arrays, int

I'm trying to create an object by converting an 'int' to a 'String'. I'm working on an ADT stack program but I was asked to use data type String.

*I was able to figure out:

```
int top = -1;
String stkTop = Integer.toString(top);
```

*But how do I create this int to String?

```
int[] data;
data = new int[10];
```

Comment: What is in your `data` array? You want to concatenate 10 integers into a single String? Like '1234567890'?

Comment: This is not an `int`, but an *array* of (10) `int`s

Comment: What does ADT stack mean? the `adt` tag here means "Android Development Tools"

Comment: Can't you just loop through the array and add them one by one into a StringBuilder structure for example? Otherwise, there is a constructor to create a String from a byte array - but it's `byte`, not `int`. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: ADT is Abstract Data Type.

Comment: Your question contains no `Stack` objects or `abstract` references, though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.toString()` to accomplish this

```
String stkTop = Arrays.toString(data);
```

Comment: What about `Arrays.toString(data)`?

Comment: Why the detour? You can simply use `Arrays.toString(data)`

Comment: Arrays.toString(data) returns with the brackets "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" if he doesnt need he would probably have to substring the result.

Comment: @EduardoDennis `Arrays.asList(data).toString()` yields the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the values for the array you can just do a simple for loop.

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
String numbers = "";

for(int x=0; x<data.length; x++){
    numbers = numbers + data[x] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public String intArrayToString(int[] in){

    Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int x : data) 
            sb.append(x);

    return sb;
}
```