# How to receive a byte array inside a JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, arraybuffer

I'm trying to receive a PDF from server that will be wrapped inside a JSON.

If I am only sending a byte array of the pdf to the front-end, I can read it properly by setting `responseType` to `arraybuffer`, then I can download the PDF by:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: application/pdf});
    if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
    } else {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
    }
}
```

However when the server tries to send JSON with the bytearray inside, if I set the `responseType` to `JSON`, then I wont be able to convert the blob. But if I set `responseType` to `arrayBuffer`, I will get an Array of arrayBuffer, how do I convert it to JSON while still be able to extract the PDF afterward:

The JSON I'm receiving is in the form:

```
{
  result: true,
  value: <the pdf byte array>,
  errorMessage: null
}
```

Comment: JSON isn't designed for binary content. You have to use a string format, so you have to encode the binary into a string format, and decode it after to make it back into a binary. I highly recommend you to use base64 as answered by Petr Averyanov

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should convert bytes to base64 String and on UI read bytes from it.

Answer (score 10):

If the below variable is assumed to represent the structure of responseText:

```
responseText = {
      result: true,
      value: <the pdf byte array>,
      errorMessage: null
}
```

`responseText.value` is the byte array. If the byte array is already typed as Uint8Array then this would work.

(**Note: Other [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) exist, so choose which ever one suits your case best**):

```
var blob = new Blob([response.value], { type: 'application/pdf'});
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
} else {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = fileURL;
    a.download = 'test';//filename
    a.click();
}
```

However, if there is a string array, or integer array, of bytes like below:

`responseText.value = [145, 229, 216, 110, 3]`

and it needs to be converted to a typed byte array, then the below would work:

```
var ba = new Uint8Array(responseText.value);
```

**or**

```
var ba = new Uint8Array([145, 229, 216, 110, 3]);
```

Therefore,

```
var blob = new Blob([ba], { type: 'application/pdf'});
```

This way the byte array can be used to create a blob, so the file is downloaded when the `click` event fires.

Comment: Not that this answer says anything wrong in itself, but **I hope nobody does this**. If we take the exact example in this answer, then the binary data is actually only **5 bytes**. Representing it as an Array of Uint8 converted to a string encoded as UTF-8, we now have a **23 bytes** payload (~336% bigger). The base64 equivalent, (`keXYbgM=`) even with optional padding is only **8 bytes** (~36% bigger than original).

Answer (score -1):

Set the byte array value as string.
When parsing the JSON convert the string into byte array.

reference this [Java Byte Array to String to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array) for an example.