# Manage user logged in sessions in Spring MVC + AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I was making an application with Spring which is providing the backend with the REST Api's and Angular managing the views part of the Application.
I had a couple of questions.

I was thinking of maintaining a sessions in the app so that I can track the logged in Users and also know when they logout and other things. Moreover the Api's should be authenticated using token.

My setup is Spring + Angular and PostgreSQL for Database and Hibernate as ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To track **login** - You need to define a Spring Bean which implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener.

Then, in your code, do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

@Component
public class myLoginListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent appEvent)
{
    if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent)
    {
        AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = (AuthenticationSuccessEvent) appEvent;
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        //track the logged in Users here ....
    }
}
```

2.To track **logout** - write a listener by implementing **HttpSessionListener** and use Spring **Security** as below..

sessionDestroyed() will be called **just before** the session is going to destroyed.

```
@Component
public class mySessionListener implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener{

   @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();

    SecurityContextImpl springSecurityContext = (SecurityContextImpl)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    if(springSecurityContext!=null){
        Authentication authentication = springSecurityContext.getAuthentication();
        LdapUserDetails userDetails = (LdapUserDetailsImpl)authentication.getPrincipal();
     //track user logout here

}
...
```

You can refer this tutorial - [Secure AnugularJS applications with spring security](https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/secure-angularjs-application-with-spring-security/)

and this tutorial from the [official site](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/).

Comment: how do i generate tokens for login and do i track them using spring or angular?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992972/how-to-create-a-authentication-token-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Spring security framework:

[spring security official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer)

[Spring security getting started example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Comment: any way to do it in angular? have any more links for examples?

Comment: For spring security you will have to define a login form (which is an html file), so yes, inside this page you can use angular.