# Binary to Text and just reverse it to binary using JAVA

Tags: java, binary

I am new in Java.I have changed binary String  to text string Using this code.

```
   StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));
    String jitu;
    while ((jitu = in.readLine()) != null) {
        contentBuilder.append(jitu);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
    String binput = contentBuilder.toString();     
     for (int i = 0; i < binput.length()/8; i++)
    {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(binput.substring(8*i,(i+1)*8),2);
       sb.append((char)(a));
    }
```

Then I want to reverse this text to binary by following code.

```
      byte[] bytes = binput.getBytes();
  StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : bytes){
     int val = b;
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
     binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
     val <<= 1;
     }}
```

But the problem is When I will getting the output from binary.append(). that is not the same as the the input binary string.I want output same as input.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you try to do this you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: I suggest you use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.  The latter became a legacy class more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If your file really contains binary (as in, not character data), then the way you are reading it in is almost guaranteed to lose data.  You are transforming binary to a string using the default charset.  On many systems, the default charset is UTF-8.  Many binary sequences do not map to a valid unicode character, in those cases if you are interpreting that data as UTF-8, the default behavior is to replace that data with a set replacement character.  That means you're going to lose a lot of data.

If you really want to read in binary data as a String (which may well not be a good approach), use a charset which has a mapping for every possible bit sequence (such as Windows-1252) so that you can be sure you won't lose any data.