# How to convert array of byte to String in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How can I convert a array of `bytes` to `String` without conversion?.

I tried:

```
  String doc=new String( bytes);
```

But the doc file is not the same than the bytes (the bytes are **binary information**). For example:

```
  String doc=new String( bytes);
  byte[] bytes2=doc.getBytes();
```

`bytes` and `bytes2` are different.

PS: UTF-8 Does not work because it convert some bytes in different values. I tested and it does not work.

PS2: And no, I don't want `BASE64`.

Comment: you have to use a proper encoding

Comment: @TheNewIdiot the answer in that post solve nothing.  I wish for a byte to byte conversion and the answer say "convert it or bust".  How is it possible that Java can't do that?.

Comment: Java makes a superb distinction between binary data (bytes) and text (String). For text they chose internally Unicode, so all languages are covered. Though you can use an encoding like ISO-8559-1 to convert bytes as they are to a String and vice versa, these Strings may have artifacts like a binary 0.

Comment: You almost certainly _do_ want Base64, which is the only way you're going to get reversible byte-to-String encoding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding you want e.g. for UTF-8

```
String doc = ....
byte[] bytes = doc.getBytes("UTF-8");
String doc2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

`doc` and `doc2` will be the same.

To decode a `byte[]` you need to know what encoding was used to be sure it will decode correctly.

Answer (score 14):

Here's one way to convert an array of bytes into a `String` and back:

```
String doc=new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
byte[] bytes2=doc.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

A `String` is a sequence of characters, so you'll have to somehow encode bytes as characters. The `ISO-8859-1` encoding maps a single, unique character for each byte, so it's safe to use it for the conversion. Note that other encodings, such as `UTF-8`, are not safe in this sense because there are sequences of bytes that don't map to valid strings in those encodings.

Comment: This works in Java, as even binary 0 (C string terminator) goes well.

Comment: Greatly Helped Me! Otherwise, I would have been struggling with byte[]!

Comment: Nice tip regarding `ISO-8859-1` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The "proper conversion" between byte[] and String is to explicitly state the encoding you want to use. If you start with a byte[] and it does not in fact contain text data, there is no "proper conversion". Strings are for text, byte[] is for binary data, and the only really sensible thing to do is to avoid converting between them unless you absolutely have to.

If you really must use a String to hold binary data then the safest way is to use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536365/2502012) by Michael Borgwardt

Comment: What if the string is only a representation? and on converting back to the byte array we use proper conversion methods?