# How to hash a string using SHA-256

Tags: java, string, hash, sha256

**I am trying to hash my users password which is of string type using SHA-256**

I am using SHA-256 to hash the string using the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531455/how-to-encode-some-string-with-sha256-in-java)

```
String text = "abc";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

To convert the btye array to string , I used the following [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574916/how-to-convert-array-of-byte-to-string-in-java)

```
String doc2 = new String(hash, "UTF-8");
```

When i print doc2 to output , i get rubbish

```
�x����AA@�]�"#�a��z���a�
```

What am i doing wrong ??? How do i hash a string using SHA-256  and convert it back to string ??

Comment: Hashing is a one way function. If your intention is to try and get back the password from the hash, it is impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this will pring hex representation of hash

```
String s = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash)
```

you cannot get original string from hash

Comment: DatatypeConverter is not defined

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 returns pure binary output, with all values from 00 to FF essentially equally likely for each character.

For text output, you'll need to convert it to a text form, like [Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Test".getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
```

The only way to go from a cryptographically sound hash (or most hashes, even cryptographically unsound ones) back to the original input is to apply the hash to input after input until you get the same result - that's either the original input, or a collision.