# Hex to String in Android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, string, hex, byte

Maybe I was sticky in hex to String?I don't know.
my code:

```
final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
```

txValue should be byte ?

debug:

```
Log.d("p1", ""+txValue.toString());
```

then show me those:

```
[B@1e631929
[B@9264ae
```

I don't know how to fix it ? somebody help me ?

Comment: Try Arrays.toString(txValue) ? (But that won't print in hex, so ignore this comment!)

Comment: [convert byte array to string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1536054/2764279)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`public String(byte[] bytes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) constructor:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset. The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the byte array.

```
String s = new String(txValue);
```

and then print `s`, it contains what you want.

Printing `txValue` and `txValue.toString()` will print it in byte format.

Comment: I did it before,but it's not working.Still show [B@367d19dc,I found that data maybe like this: b11011011 , and I had to find out the way can show correct data from final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);

Answer (score 0):

I find the way:
final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);

final int GasValue = ((txValue[0]<<8)|(txValue[1]&0xff))&0xffff;

String text = Integer.toString(GasValue);

Log.d("p1", ""+text);

OK

Answer (score 0):

You should use Arrays.toString(txValue)

This is how I use i code

```
 final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
   txtResult.setText(Arrays.toString(txValue));
```

Result is like below
[27,0,1,13,13,4,5]