# convert byteArray to string to initialize jsonObject

Tags: android, json, arrays

i have byteArray.

is it possible to convert byteArray to String?

please check my code

```
        byte[] data = **some_byte_array**
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
```

how do i fix this.

Comment: what do you exactly want to do here? Upload a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
String decoded = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

There are a bunch of encodings you can use, look at the Charset class in the [Sun javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).

The "proper conversion" between byte[] and String is to explicitly state the encoding you want to use. If you start with a byte[] and it does not in fact contain text data, there is no "proper conversion". Strings are for text, byte[] is for binary data, and the only really sensible thing to do is to avoid converting between them unless you absolutely have to.

answer credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536365/4211264

Comment: JSON is *almost always* encoded in UTF-8 (see, for example [the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1)). It's not guaranteed, but it's one of the times where guessing has a pretty good success rate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert byte array to String using one of the String constructors like this :

```
String myString = new String(yourByteArray);
```

Documentation for the same: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])

All the best :)