# JAVA , String to byte array byte size

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I've got problem with converting byte array to string and back :) I get byte array from api which is 10 bytes long. When I convert it to String i"m getting String with 20 chars for example "12345678901234567890" so it looks like there are 2 chars on one byte. However when I try to send it back with simply getText() from editText :

`String namespace = mNamespaceTv.getText().toString();`

byte array created from that string is 20 bytes long, so one char to one byte. I need to send it back again as 10 byte array. Why it happened and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Very unclear what you're actually asking. How can you encode 20 bytes in 10 bytes? (Short of compressing it)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't want to encode anything. Just try to understand what happened.

Comment: I suspect you represent the byte as Hex, In Hex, one byte will usually be represented by 2 "digits" 0-F for example "8F" => 1 byte = 2 chars ... Each of which will be represented by 1 byte in UTF-8 or ASCII.

Comment: "I don't want to encode anything" - I guess you did accidentally.

Comment: Why would you convert a byte array to a string? Is the data text?

Comment: Yes, it is , indeed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really clear what you are asking, but consider that the size of the byte array generated from a String depends from the Charset used.

For example:

```
"ABC".getBytes("UTF-16")   --> array of size 8
"ABC".getBytes("UTF-8")    --> array of size 3
"ABC".getBytes("US-ASCII") --> array of size 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `byte[]` use `new String(mNamespaceTv.getText())` rather than `toString()`