# Why strange symbols appear on android screen?

Tags: java, android, textview, serial-port, settext

If enter string data, my code do serial send/read data correctly. If data is Hex, although my serial send/read data correctly textview output is strange.Why strange symbols appear on android screen?

My input:

```
0067123456789123456789123456FF8E6457DF0215DF820803111111DF820903222222DF820A03333333DF6F3CDFEF0602AAAADFEF0B08BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBDFEF0E20CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDFEF0402DDDD1D
```

My Received Data method:

```
private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) throws InterruptedException {

   String s = new String(data);   
   text2.setText("Incoming Mesage = " + s);
   SendSerialData(data, data.length);

}
```

My Serial Output on Hterm(TRUE):

```
0067123456789123456789123456FF8E6457DF0215DF820803111111DF820903222222DF820A03333333DF6F3CDFEF0602AAAADFEF0B08BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBDFEF0E20CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDFEF0402DDDD1D
```

My textview output:

```
��g4Vx�#Eg�4V��dW�߂߂   """߂
333�o<���������������� 
������������������������������������
```

Comment: It looks like you have a character encoding issue. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Thank you, but it wasn't usefull for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. Instead of:

```
String s = new String(data);
```

Use:

```
String s =  byteArrayToHex(data);
```

And add this method:

```
public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
    for(byte b: a)
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    return sb.toString();
}
```