# Strange conversion of bytes to and from string

Tags: java, string, byte, filecontentresult

I have a mini server

```
byte[] content = fileManager.get(request.getUri());
```

Here I get the contents of the files on the server
Next I produce compression and chunking

```
content = process(content, response);

private byte[] process(byte[] content, Response response) {
    ProcessorList processors = new ProcessorList();
    processors.add(new CompressDelegator(new GZIPCompressor()));
    processors.add(new ChunkDelegator(new Chunker(30)));
    content = processors.process(content, response);
    return content;
}
```

After that, something amazing happens
Now in the compressed and chunked content of the file

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(content));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String(content).getBytes()));
```

Two of these will print different answers. Why?

Comment: Why do you think they should print the same? You are doing entirely different things. A good starting point would be the javadoc for the String constructor that you invoke

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert byte array to string and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you. But, how i can print the same

Answer (score 2):

```
new String(content).getBytes()
```

is round-tripping a `byte[]` to a `String` to a `byte[]`.

You are converting the `byte[]` to a `String` using the JVM's default charset. If the `byte[]` contains byte sequences which are invalid according to that charset, those bytes can't be accurately converted to `char`, so they will be converted to... something you don't expect in the `String`; so they won't be the same as the input when you convert back to `byte[]`.

Don't do this: `String` is *not* logically a `byte[]`, it is a `char[]`. If you want to transmit a `byte[]` in a `String`, do something like base64-encoding it first.