# Strange Java Base64.decode Results

Tags: javascript, java, php, base64

I have a base64 encoded string.
`"jZsq4NNN0K4HzssoDEakhImknSVHLWpsmIF2AEBNacLykXJWBK9VKmCuuX1SR5iMNlfqXe7/eP8oLFEZp50E3g=="`

When I trying decode with php (`base64_decode`)

**Result:** `��*��MЮ��(F�����%G-jl��v@Mi��rV�U*`��}RG��6W�]��x�(,Q���`

When I trying with javascript (`window.atob`)

**Result:** `*àÓMÐ®ÎË(F¤¤%G-jlv@MiÂòrV¯U*`®¹}RG6Wê]îÿxÿ(,Q§Þ"`

Now we came strange part.

Now I trying with JDK 1.8.0_201 (`Base64.getDecoder().decode`)

**Result:** `[B@4e25154f`

Now with JDK 1.8.0_66

**Result:** `[B@2a139a55`

Lets try with latest JDK (10.0.1),

**Result:** `[B@6073f712`

As you can see, different results in every version.
I don't know why and I want to learn.

**Edit:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
    System.out.print(version + " || " + decodeMeee());
  }
  private static String decodeMeee() {
    return newBase64.getDecoder().decode("jZsq4NNN0K4HzssoDEakhImknSVHLWpsmIF2AEBNacLykXJWBK9VKmCuuX1SR5iMNlfqXe7/eP8oLFEZp50E3g==");
    }
```

And now I tried same thing with converting manually. It seems go with the grain.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
    System.out.print(version + " || " + decodeMeee());
  }
  private static String decodeMeee() {
    return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("jZsq4NNN0K4HzssoDEakhImknSVHLWpsmIF2AEBNacLykXJWBK9VKmCuuX1SR5iMNlfqXe7/eP8oLFEZp50E3g=="));
    }
```

Comment: Add some code that shows how you decode it. Probably you're using the wrong encoding - try `utf-8`.

Comment: Please share the full code for all tests, this helps others to inspect your problem

Comment: You're not calling the correct method to display your decoded string value or not using UTF-8. Please edit your post with your code.

Comment: Regarding `[B@4e25154f` [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784). Also this may interest you: [How to convert byte array to string and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536054)

Comment: Gomennasai! I added sample codes.

Comment: The base64 string doesn't seem to include any printable chracters? Test yourself here: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Actaully, my problem is not that. Why result changing in every jdk version when I return my data as byte[]?

Comment: "Why result changing in every jdk version when I return my data as byte[]" are you are referring to `[B@4e25154f` and `[B@2a139a55`? Then they don't change based on JDK version, but based on current memory structure since it shows `Type@HexHashCode` and native hashcode of array is based on its memory location.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it ..., so it's not `UTF-8`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        System.out.print(version + " || " + decodeMeee());
    }

    private static String decodeMeee() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] content = Base64.getDecoder()
                .decode("jZsq4NNN0K4HzssoDEakhImknSVHLWpsmIF2AEBNacLykXJWBK9VKmCuuX1SR5iMNlfqXe7/eP8oLFEZp50E3g==");
        return new String(content, 0, content.length, "UTF-8"); // <-- replace with correct encoding format
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
12.0.2    || ��*��MЮ��(F�����%G-jl��v
10.0.2    || ��*��MЮ��(F�����%G-jl��v
1.8.0_151 || ��*��MЮ��(F�����%G-jl��v
```

PS:

> Lets try with latest JDK (10.0.1),

Definitely not the latest ;)

Comment: Umm, definetly latest in online compiler :)

Comment: What online compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using jdoodle and compilejava for tests.