# Read uploadedFile's content with it's original format string(text)

Tags: java, primefaces

I uploaded a file and i can get the file name, type, size and content. The content is in a format of byte array. I want the cotnet in it's original format, which is text file(String). Is there a way to read the uploadedFile of the primefaces like the File in io. or is there a way i can read the content in a string format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Comment: @WoAiNii, no, you don't want to save it to a file first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. The uploaded file will contain a `byte[]` of the contents of the uploaded file, so you can simply construct a `String` from it:

```
public void handleUpload(final FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
  String content = new String(event.getFile().getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

See also:

- [How to convert byte array to string and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa)