# What is the encoding format of the byte arrays returned by ApkChecksum's getValue()?

Tags: android, hash, checksum, android-package-managers

Starting from API level 31, android's package manager has added [requestChecksums()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#requestChecksums(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.security.cert.Certificate%3E,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.OnChecksumsReadyListener)), allowing various apk hashes to be retrieved. With this, we can obtain a `List<ApkChecksum>`; however, the [developer reference for ApkChecksum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApkChecksum) very sparsely documents the ApkChecksum class. `getValue()` returns "Checksum value" as a byte array (byte[]). And it cannot be null.

But it doesn't say anything about the encoding/format of the bytes thus returned. As [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa) indicates, "Your byte array must have some encoding." and it points to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/intl/supported-encodings.html#GUID-F8900850-51B5-4B8B-88C0-6186DF1C16B5 for a list of dozens of basic encoding sets contained in just `java.base` module, not to mention many others that developers may have chosen to use. And those are just character encodings, whereas hashes returned by ApkChecksum may presumably used other encodings/formats for numbers or big numbers.

Does anyone know what is the encoding for the byte array returned by ApkChecksum's `getValue()`?

Comment: Are you asking for string encoding? Probably UTF-8? Or the hash encoding, which I think is SHA256

Comment: For example, when we try with to get the TYPE_WHOLE_MERKLE_ROOT_4K_SHA256 checksum of a sample apk, and then just print the checksum returned value (a byte array), as a string, it shows as [B@3e70406 ; we go to a site like https://www.tunnelsup.com/hash-analyzer/ and it can't recognize the hash format. These 10 bytes are very different from a typical 64-byte SHA256 hash that the site can recognize.

Comment: [B@3e70406 is a memory address, so not a hash. TYPE_WHOLE_MERKLE_ROOT_4K_SHA256 is of course SHA256 - have you tried to use a SHA256 parser on the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I referred to [this page](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/convert-byte-array-hexadecimal) which uses `String.format ("%02X", b)` to print the Hex value into a string, and concatenated the output to form the hash. My code looks something like this:

```
                val Checksum = checksum.value
                var concatWhole = ""
                for (a in Checksum) {
                    val st = String.format("%02X", a)
                    concatWhole += st
```

Android is little-endian according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this field, but AFAIK checksums are just bytes (not text) so they don't need any encoding.

If your question is how do you interpret the bytes, then you probably need to look at the reported type (e.g. [TYPE_PARTIAL_MERKLE_ROOT_1M_SHA256](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Checksum#TYPE_PARTIAL_MERKLE_ROOT_1M_SHA256)):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApkChecksum#getType()

The [documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning) has a lot of details about the signature algorithms.